# Spring Integration: Aggregator to expire message on timeout

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using SI's aggregator pattern to hold events and wait for the completion events and storing it in JdbcMessage store. I have created the table INT_MESSAGE, INT_MESSAGE_GROUP and INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE.

Sometimes, the completion event may not be available and I want to complete and discard the event, remove it from the tables. I don't want the tables to grow big un-necessarily

I have specified the below config in the pipeline

```
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        .expireGroupsUponTimeout(true)
                        .groupTimeout(groupMessageTimeOut)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(false)
```

Would this ensure if the completion event doesn't arrive in x minutes then the message group will be expired, discarded in the null channel and removed from the tables.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Your summary is correct. Both `.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)` &                      `.expireGroupsUponTimeout(true)` do remove a group from the store.
The `sendPartialResultOnExpiry(false)` really does what you are asking:

```
if (this.sendPartialResultOnExpiry) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Prematurely releasing partially complete group with key ["
                    + correlationKey + "] to: " + getOutputChannel());
        }
        completeGroup(correlationKey, group, lock);
    }
    else {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Discarding messages of partially complete group with key ["
                    + correlationKey + "] to: "
                    + (this.discardChannelName != null ? this.discardChannelName : this.discardChannel));
        }
        if (this.releaseLockBeforeSend) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        group.getMessages()
                .forEach(this::discardMessage);
    }
```

Tell us, please, what made you to be confused about that configuration?